# Sql select statement fetch value based on user choice

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I am developing application where user can search using Destination put in database. Highest priority is to "destination". Then in advanced search option, I have to give choices to user like

- Gender
- Type of vehicle
- Ac/Non Ac
- Fare

layout is like this

[image: Mobile screen layout]
[image: Front screen]

Operations to be done:

I have to generate listview from database based on user selection. User can select max 4 parameters at a time bt may select 1 or 2 or 3 random options. Now I am confused how to call this based on my database architecture. Any suggestion will be much more helpful as I'm stuck up on this for hours. Thanx

Edit:

Now i have created one view that gives my answer. Just one last error remaining. duplicate entries are populated based on different parameters. like user A having 2 2wheeler and 1 4wheeler is shown thrice. similarly user having 2 vehicle gets duplicate name entry. screen shot as follows:

[image: uodated]

My query-

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT T.name, TM.source_latitude, TM.source_longitude, TM.trvl_day, TM.trvl_time, TM.dest_latitude, TM.dest_longitude, T.email, T.contactno, TM.trvl_source, TM.Trvl_vehicle, 
                  TM.Seats_available, T.gender, TM.user_id, TM.trvl_destination, dbo.tbl_vh.type, dbo.tbl_vh.AcNonAc, dbo.tbl_vh.kmrate FROM         dbo.tbl_reg1 AS T INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Travel_master AS TM ON T.userid = TM.user_id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_vh ON TM.user_id = dbo.tbl_vh.userid WHERE     (TM.trvl_destination LIKE '%' + @trvl_destination + '%') AND (T.gender = ISNULL(@gender, T.gender)) AND (dbo.tbl_vh.type = ISNULL(@type, dbo.tbl_vh.type)) AND 
                  (dbo.tbl_vh.kmrate = ISNULL(@kmrate, dbo.tbl_vh.kmrate)) AND (dbo.tbl_vh.AcNonAc = ISNULL(@AcNonAc, dbo.tbl_vh.AcNonAc)) ORDER BY TM.trvl_day
```

Comment: _Now I am confused how to call this based on my database architecture_ To answer this we need to see your database architecture. Also the screenshots you give seem to be a android system. Android is written in java so I'm not sure if you want to tag it as c#. Last, its never a good idea to directly connect a mobile device to a database. Consider using / making a API service.

Comment: I am actually using android app for carpooling service. it gives parameters to .net webservice. So i tagged c#. And while writing this question i had not written single sql query for that solution so couldn't put up DB details. Now i Have got my answer jst one error remaining. Duplicate enties are shown in result set .  see edit plz

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i did what exactly i wanted. Did goup by on name and day column. Finalized query as follows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT T.name, TM.trvl_day FROM dbo.tbl_reg1 AS T INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Travel_master AS TM ON T.userid = TM.user_id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tbl_vh ON TM.user_id = dbo.tbl_vh.userid WHERE (TM.trvl_destination LIKE '%' + @trvl_destination + '%') AND (T.gender = ISNULL(@gender, T.gender)) AND (dbo.tbl_vh.type = ISNULL(@type, dbo.tbl_vh.type)) AND 
                  (dbo.tbl_vh.kmrate = ISNULL(@kmrate, dbo.tbl_vh.kmrate)) AND (dbo.tbl_vh.AcNonAc = ISNULL(@AcNonAc, dbo.tbl_vh.AcNonAc)) GROUP BY T.name, TM.trvl_day ORDER BY TM.trvl_day
```